# enum getter returning wrong value

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum Type

```
public enum Type {
        A("abc1", "desc1"),
        B("abc2", "desc2"),
        C("abc3", "desc3"),
        D("abc4", "desc4"),
        E("abc5", "desc5");

        private String value;
        private String description;

        private Type(String value, String description) {
            this.value = value;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

I get the values from the enum through the following code

```
Type[] type = Type.values();

for (int i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(type[i].getValue());
}
```

This code runs on a server. For few days it runs fine and the output of this code is as follows :

```
abc1
abc2
abc3
abc4
abc5
```

But after few days the output changes to

```
abc1
abc2
abc1
abc4
abc5
```

If I print the description then they are always correct.

I am not able to figure out why Type.getValue() is returning value of enum Value A for enum Value C.

Comment: "But after few days the output changes to" - This made me laugh :) Are there other running threads somewhere?

Comment: Mutable enums feel like a very bad idea. Make `value` final, remove the setter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820149/enum-values-is-an-order-of-returned-enums-deterministic

Comment: sure that nobody ever calls `setValue()`?

Comment: Are you are that `setValue()` is not being called at some point by mistake? Not a good idea to have the ability to change something in an `enum`. The whole point of `enum` is to be an unchangeable list of items that you can control as the developer, to limit the options of the user to those in the list.

Comment: Remove setValue() and let us know if it worked in a few days.

Comment: I searched the entire package and found that setValue is being called for Type C. Now, I have removed that and made the values final in the enum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your enum is mutable; something is calling `setValue()`.

You should make your enum [immutable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) - it makes good sense to do this. Make it immutable by making the fields final and ditching the setters:

```
public enum Type {
    A("abc1", "desc1"),
    B("abc2", "desc2"),
    C("abc3", "desc3"),
    D("abc4", "desc4"),
    E("abc5", "desc5");

    private final String value;
    private final String description;

    private Type(String value, String description) {
        this.value = value;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

}
```